# Node.js app crashes as it doesn't find files mounted from Kubernetes Secrets keys files

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm changing my Node.js app from using .env variables to use files stored in the `api/src/config/values` directory.
So I'm mounting the secrets as volumes and mounting the volumes for the container with `mountPath: /api/src/config/values`. I'm trying to get all the files from secrets in a single directory, so I'm trying a single volumeMount and a single projected volume.

```
          volumeMounts:
            - name: secrets
              # mountPath: /app/api/src/config/values
              mountPath: /api/src/config/values
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: secrets
          projected: 
            sources:
            - secret:
              name: server-secret
              items:
                - key: server-api-key
                  path: server-api-key
                - key: m-port-k8s
                  path: m-port-k8s
                - key: m-db-k8s
                  path: m-db-k8s
                - key: m-username-k8s
                  path: m-username-k8s
                - key: m-password-k8s
                  path: m-password-k8s
                - key: m-hostname-k8s
                  key: m-hostname-k8s
                - key: database-url
                  key: database-url
                - key: app-listening-port
                  path: app-listening-port

            - secret:
              name: stripe-secret
              items:
                - key: stripe-key
                  path: stripe-key
            - secret:
              name: openai-secret
              items: 
                - key: openai-key
                  path: openai-key
                - key: openai-organization
                  path: openai-organization
            - secret:
              name: neo4j-secret
              items:
                - key: n-protocol-k8s
                  path: n-protocol-k8s
                - key: n-host-k8s
                  path: n-host-k8s
                - key: n-port-k8s
                  path: n-port-k8s
                - key: n-username-k8s
                  path: n-username-k8s
                - key: n-password-k8s
                  path: n-password-k8s
            - secret:
              name: mongo-secret
              items:
                - key: m-username-k8s
                  path: m-username-k8s
                - key: m-password-k8s
                  path: m-password-k8s
                - key: m-hostname-k8s
                  path: m-hostname-k8s
                - key: m-port-k8s
                  path: m-port-k8s
                - key: m-db-k8s
                  path: m-db-k8s
```

When I deploy the chart I do get warning for every secret name that I'm referencing and the container goes in CrashLoopBackOff as the Node.js app crashes because it doesn't find the files in the given directory.

```
W1031 11:51:05.199988   50914 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.template.spec.volumes[0].projected.sources[0].items"
W1031 11:51:05.200007   50914 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.template.spec.volumes[0].projected.sources[0].name"
W1031 11:51:05.200010   50914 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.template.spec.volumes[0].projected.sources[1].items"
W1031 11:51:05.200011   50914 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.template.spec.volumes[0].projected.sources[1].name"
W1031 11:51:05.200013   50914 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.template.spec.volumes[0].projected.sources[2].items"
W1031 11:51:05.200014   50914 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.template.spec.volumes[0].projected.sources[2].name"
W1031 11:51:05.200016   50914 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.template.spec.volumes[0].projected.sources[3].items"
W1031 11:51:05.200017   50914 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.template.spec.volumes[0].projected.sources[3].name"
W1031 11:51:05.200018   50914 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.template.spec.volumes[0].projected.sources[4].items"
W1031 11:51:05.200107   50914 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.template.spec.volumes[0].projected.sources[4].name"
NAME: server
LAST DEPLOYED: Tue Oct 31 11:51:04 2023
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
```

When I describe the pod dough the volume seems to be mounted correctly, but then when I exec into it there is no files from secrets inside the api/scr/config/values, only the one which  already is part of the Node.js app image:

```
Containers:
  fixit-server-container:
    Container ID:   containerd://58ef22fa04fa6b2cc231055da97915410de33041be289ded31aa6d627e38af43
    Image:          vinnytwice/fixit-server:dev
    Image ID:       docker.io/vinnytwice/fixit-server@sha256:a14ed6f5e66dcd0191b4c9fc9ce90836e00a5e4714813cd7f1d7f3e1f5d11587
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Fri, 03 Nov 2023 08:44:45 +0100
      Finished:     Fri, 03 Nov 2023 08:44:45 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  1
    Limits:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  200Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        500m
      memory:     200Mi
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /api/src/config/values from secrets (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  secrets:
    Type:        Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
```

I then tried changing the Node.js app from looking for the files in the single `values` folder to a dedicated folder for each secret.
So I mounted each Secret in its own Volume and mount them in separate directories.

```
          volumeMounts:
            - name: server-secret
              mountPath: /api/src/config/values/server-secret
              readOnly: true
            - name: stripe-secret
              mountPath: /api/src/config/values/stripe-secret
              readOnly: true
            - name: openai-secret
              mountPath: /api/src/config/values/openai-secret
              readOnly: true
            - name: neo4j-secret
              mountPath: /api/src/config/values/neo4j-secret
              readOnly: true
            - name: mongo-secret
              mountPath: /api/src/config/values/mongo-secret
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: server-secret
          secret:
            secretName: server-secret
        - name: stripe-secret
          secret:
            secretName: stripe-secret
        - name: openai-secret
          secret:
            secretName: openai-secret
        - name: neo4j-secret
          secret:
            secretName: neo4j-secret
        - name: mongo-secret
          secret:
            secretName: mongo-secret
```

The Node.js app still crashes as it doesn't find the files inside the directories causing the container CrashLoopBackOff.

```
node:internal/fs/utils:345
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './api/src/config/values/server-secret/database-url'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:591:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:459:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/app/api/src/app.js:11:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/app/server.js:9:13) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: './api/src/config/values/server-secret/database-url'
}
```

this is the server-secret

```
Name:         server-secret
Namespace:    default
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:  meta.helm.sh/release-name: server-secrets
              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
m-password-k8s:      8 bytes
m-port-k8s:          5 bytes
m-username-k8s:      10 bytes
server-api-key:      33 bytes
app-listening-port:  4 bytes
database-url:        34 bytes
m-db-k8s:            5 bytes
m-hostname-k8s:      48 bytes
```

and this is how I read the files in Node.js app.js

```
const serverSecretPath = './api/src/config/values';
const databaseURL_b64 = fs.readFileSync(
  `${serverSecretPath}/server-secret/database-url`,
  'utf8'
);
const databaseURL = Buffer.from(databaseURL_b64, 'base64').toString('utf8');
```

and server.js

```
const serverSecretPath = './api/src/config/values';
const port_b64 =
  fs.readFileSync(
    `${serverSecretPath}/server-secret/app-listening-port`,
    'utf8'
  );
  const port = Buffer.from(port_b64, 'base64')  || 5000;
```

This is the Deployment yaml file for the pod

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  # name: fixit-server
  name: {{ .Values.server_deployment.name }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace}}
# Deployment specs
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      # app: fixit-server-pod
      app: {{ .Values.server_deployment.pod_name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        # app: fixit-server-pod
        app: {{ .Values.server_deployment.pod_name }}
        namespace: {{ .Values.namespace}}
    # Pod specs
    spec:
      automountServiceAccountToken: false
      # securityContext:
      #   # privileged: false
      #   allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
      #   # runAsNonRoot: true
      #   runAsUser: 1000
      # #   readOnlyRootFilesystem: true

      # nodeSelector:       
      #   server-type: server
      

      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: docker-secret
      containers:
        - name: fixit-server-container
          # securityContext:
          #   # privileged: false
          #   # allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          #   # runAsNonRoot: true
          #   runAsUser: 2000
          # #   readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          image: {{ .Values.server_deployment.image_name }}:{{ .Values.server_deployment.image_tag }}
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.server_deployment.image_pull_policy}}
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: {{.Values.server_deployment.container_specs.resources.requests.memory}}
              cpu: {{.Values.server_deployment.container_specs.resources.requests.cpu}}
            limits:
              memory: {{.Values.server_deployment.container_specs.resources.limits.memory}}
              cpu: {{.Values.server_deployment.container_specs.resources.limits.cpu}}
          volumeMounts:
            # - name: secrets
            #   # mountPath: /app/api/src/config/values
            #   mountPath: /api/src/config/values
            #   readOnly: true


            - name: server-secret
              mountPath: /api/src/config/values/server-secret
              readOnly: true
            - name: stripe-secret
              mountPath: /api/src/config/values/stripe-secret
              readOnly: true
            - name: openai-secret
              mountPath: /api/src/config/values/openai-secret
              readOnly: true
            - name: neo4j-secret
              mountPath: /api/src/config/values/neo4j-secret
              readOnly: true
            - name: mongo-secret
              mountPath: /api/src/config/values/mongo-secret
              readOnly: true

      volumes:
        - name: server-secret
          secret:
            secretName: server-secret
        - name: stripe-secret
          secret:
            secretName: stripe-secret
        - name: openai-secret
          secret:
            secretName: openai-secret
        - name: neo4j-secret
          secret:
            secretName: neo4j-secret
        - name: mongo-secret
          secret:
            secretName: mongo-secret


        # - name: secrets
        #   projected: 
        #     sources:
        #     - secret:
        #       name: server-secret
        #       items:
        #         - key: server-api-key
        #           path: server-api-key
        #         - key: m-port-k8s
        #           path: m-port-k8s
        #         - key: m-db-k8s
        #           path: m-db-k8s
        #         - key: m-username-k8s
        #           path: m-username-k8s
        #         - key: m-password-k8s
        #           path: m-password-k8s
        #         - key: m-hostname-k8s
        #           key: m-hostname-k8s
        #         - key: database-url
        #           key: database-url
        #         - key: app-listening-port
        #           path: app-listening-port

        #     - secret:
        #       name: stripe-secret
        #       items:
        #         - key: stripe-key
        #           path: stripe-key
        #     - secret:
        #       name: openai-secret
        #       items: 
        #         - key: openai-key
        #           path: openai-key
        #         - key: openai-organization
        #           path: openai-organization
        #     - secret:
        #       name: neo4j-secret
        #       items:
        #         - key: n-protocol-k8s
        #           path: n-protocol-k8s
        #         - key: n-host-k8s
        #           path: n-host-k8s
        #         - key: n-port-k8s
        #           path: n-port-k8s
        #         - key: n-username-k8s
        #           path: n-username-k8s
        #         - key: n-password-k8s
        #           path: n-password-k8s
        #     - secret:
        #       name: mongo-secret
        #       items:
        #         - key: m-username-k8s
        #           path: m-username-k8s
        #         - key: m-password-k8s
        #           path: m-password-k8s
        #         - key: m-hostname-k8s
        #           path: m-hostname-k8s
        #         - key: m-port-k8s
        #           path: m-port-k8s
        #         - key: m-db-k8s
        #           path: m-db-k8s
```

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found where the problem was. In the container the Node.js app is in `usr/app/` directory so the path `const serverSecretPath = './api/src/config/values';` actually corresponds to  `usr/app/api/src/config/values` but secrets were wrongly mounted in `/api/src/config/values` path.

After mounting the secrets in correct paths Node.js app finally finds them in the expected directories:

```
    - name: server-secret
      mountPath: /usr/app/api/src/config/values/server-secret
      readOnly: true
    - name: stripe-secret
      mountPath: /usr/app/api/src/config/values/stripe-secret
      readOnly: true
    - name: openai-secret
      mountPath: /usr/app/api/src/config/values/openai-secret
      readOnly: true
    - name: neo4j-secret
      mountPath: /usr/app/api/src/config/values/neo4j-secret
      readOnly: true
    - name: mongo-secret
      mountPath: /usr/app/api/src/config/values/mongo-secret
      readOnly: true
```